# ASP.NET MVC PDFsharp generating PDF: cannot add font

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure, fonts, pdf-generation, pdfsharp

In my ASP.NET MVC 5 application I’m trying to generate simple PDF. My problem is that after I deploy my app into Azure the function which is generating PDFs stops working. There is an exception: "Font data could not retrieved.". So the font I use (Times New Roman) is not seen by the application server. My question is how to fix it? In my project I add a folder called "Fonts" with 4 types of Times New Roman font. In code I use only one font:

```
XPdfFontOptions options = new XPdfFontOptions(PdfFontEncoding.Unicode, PdfFontEmbedding.Always);
string Font = HostingEnvironment.MapPath(@"~/Fonts/TIMESBD.TTF");
XFont BasicFont = new XFont(Font, 16, XFontStyle.Regular, options);
```

The problem doesn’t exist on localhost. I think I should in some way "register" my font in my application, but I do not know how.

Comment: Are you using cloud services or app services? I've had a similar problem and it boils down to permissions. You have more control over that with cloud services. Though, I think some changes around this were made in a recent update to pdfsharp, but I haven't tested it.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the Time New Roman font is installed on the server - or use a private font (include the font with your project).

Give total rights to the font Time New Roman to the users group and restarted the server.

See if this helps.

Answer (score 0):

To fix this, run the application in Full Trust (if you have full control over the server) or only use private fonts.

To use private fonts, just implement IFontResolver in a class of your own. To get IFontResolver, upgrade to the latest beta version of PDFsharp 1.50.

Sample code on the PDFsharp forum:
http://forum.pdfsharp.net/viewtopic.php?p=8961#p8961

And a sample implementation that makes things easier in my blog:
http://developer.th-soft.com/developer/ezfontresolver-a-generic-font-resolver-for-pdfsharp-and-migradoc/

If you want to stick to your old version of PDFsharp, then look at XPrivateFontCollection. Sample code on the PDFsharp site:
http://pdfsharp.net/wiki/PrivateFonts-sample.ashx
I recommend switching to PDFsharp 1.50 because font handling was improved for Cloud and the older version 1.3x may still have permission problems even if you provide private fonts.